# C# Template Class for objects with different variable names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, templates, ef-code-first

I am working on an application which uses Code first database design with EF Core. I of course have a collection of models and a database context. I am trying to create a generic Data service to handle basic CRUD operations. Here is an example of the create and delete functions for a company model.

```cs
public async Task<Company> Create(Company company)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        EntityEntry<Company> newEntity = await context.Set<Company>().AddAsync(company);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return newEntity.Entity;
    }
}

public async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        Company entity = await context.Set<Company>().FirstOrDefaultAsync((e) => e.CompanySysID == id);
        context.Set<Company>().Remove(entity);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to make a template version of this service for all of my models. Obviously for the create function this would be no problem. However for the Delete function (among others), each model has a different name for their id (Primary Key) along the lines of [Model Name]SysID to follow internal conventions. It seems very against DRY to have a separate service for each model when nearly all of them are identical. Is there any way I can still make this class into a template?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeking to is a generic repository class or it's better to name it generic data access class, I already have a gist for this kind of actions and can manage all you needs, you can remove extra actions if you don't need them.

```
public interface IEntityRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : class, Entity.IEntity<TKey>
    where TKey : IComparable
{

    #region Utility
    long Count();
    Task<long> CountAsync();
    Task<bool> AnyAsync();
    Task<bool> AnyAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null);
    bool AnyLocal(Func<TEntity, bool> predicate);
    #endregion

    #region Delete
    Task<(bool success, TEntity obj)> DeleteAsync(TKey Id);
    Task<(bool success, IEnumerable<TEntity> objs)> DeleteListAsync(IEnumerable<TKey> Ids);
    Task<(bool success, IEnumerable<TEntity> objs)> DeleteListAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> guids);
    Task<(bool success, IEnumerable<TEntity> objs)> PhysicalDeleteListAsync(IEnumerable<TKey> Ids);
    Task<(bool success, IEnumerable<TEntity> objs)> PhysicalDeleteListAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> guids);
    Task BatchDeleteAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> guids);
    #endregion

    #region Update
    Task<(bool success, TEntity obj)> UpdateAsync(TEntity input);
    Task<(bool success, IEnumerable<TEntity> objs)> UpdateListAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> input);
    Task BatchUpdateAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> input);
    #endregion

    #region Create
    Task<(bool success, TEntity obj)> CreateAsync(TEntity input);
    Task<(bool success, IEnumerable<TEntity> objs)> CreateListAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> input);
    Task BatchInsertAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> input);
    #endregion

    #region Get
    Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(TKey Id, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null);
    Task<TEntity> GetByGuidAsync(Guid Id, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null);
    Task<TEntity> FirstOrDefaultAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetListByIdsAsync(IEnumerable<TKey> ids,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null);
    Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetListByGuidsAsync(IEnumerable<Guid> guids,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null);
    #endregion
}
```

gist.github:
https://gist.github.com/devlnull/cbcc3f927c36eb296e58f0d1be3e4ba2

Comment: Could you go into more detail on what your code does and how I can integrate it into what I have? This seems to be something completely different from what I am doing as opposed to a generic form.

Comment: Use the link below the code to get more details, you can find the implementation class which show you how to handle it.

Comment: Looking through the code I'm still not sure it solves my problem. Your code requires the Tentity to have a .Id property, which mine do not (at least not by name)

Comment: Create a base entity class -> Entity and define a public property name -> Id , inherit this base entity in all entities

Comment: Just updated the gist and added IEntity and Entity classes, you can get more details there.